# Adding handler in API source file through WS02 ESB management console.

Tags: basic-authentication, wso2-esb

I am trying to add a handler in the API source view in WSO2 ESB console. But I am getting the following error:Error initializing API handler: "org.wso2.api.authorization.RoleBasedAuthorizationHandler"

Following the below Blog:
http://mrmalakasilva.blogspot.com/2015/10/securing-wso2-esb-api-with-basic.html

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask a good question.  In particular, please post your actual code, not a link to a tutorial you're following.  Also, the complete stack trace would help folks help you.